# Can someone help me fix this code? (Java methods)

Tags: java, methods, static

This code is a class that displays my first name vertically down the screen and  each letter uses up to 5 rows by 5 columns of a character input by me with a blank line between each letter.

It works just fine but the problem is that I used static for the string and my profs says that there shouldn't be static anywhere in the code but main.When I remove static from string c, it breaks the code even if declare string c inside main

```
public class Lab3
{

    static String c;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Lab3 classy = new Lab3();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Which character would you like to display?");

        c = input.next();

        System.out.println("My name is Jonathan");
        classy.displayLetterJ();
        classy.displayLetterO();
        classy.displayLetterN();
        classy.displayLetterA();
        classy.displayLetterT();
        classy.displayLetterH();
        classy.displayLetterA();
        classy.displayLetterN();

    }//end of main

    public void displayLetterJ()
    {
        System.out.println("  " + c + c + c);
        System.out.println("    " + c);
        System.out.println("    " + c);
        System.out.println(c + "   " + c);
        System.out.println(c + c + c + c + c);

    }

    public void displayLetterA()
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("   " + c);
        System.out.println("  " + c + " " + c);
        System.out.println(" " + c + " " + c + " " + c);
        System.out.println(c + "     " + c);
        System.out.println(c + "     " + c);

    }

    public void displayLetterO()
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("  " + c + c);
        System.out.println(" " + c + "  " + c);
        System.out.println(c + "    " + c);
        System.out.println(c + "   " + c);
        System.out.println("  " + c + c);

    }

    public void displayLetterN()
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(c + "    " + c);
        System.out.println(c + " " + c + "  " + c);
        System.out.println(c + "  " + c + " " + c);
        System.out.println(c + "   " + c + c);
        System.out.println(c + "    " + c);

    }

    public void displayLetterH()
    {//H accessor
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(c + "   " + c);
        System.out.println(c + "   " + c);
        System.out.println(c + c + c + c + c);
        System.out.println(c + "   " + c);
        System.out.println(c + "   " + c);

    }

    public void displayLetterT()
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(c + c + c + c + c);
        System.out.println("  " + c);
        System.out.println("  " + c);
        System.out.println("  " + c);
        System.out.println("  " + c);

    }
}
```

Comment: how does it break, what error do you get?

Comment: Do you know the difference between static and non-static methods?

Comment: @all the downvoters: this is coursework, no need to downvote without clarification or at least a comment on what's wrong here.

Comment: Coursework? Your teacher should be sacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have no idea what is the purpose of this ... but this should work without the static

```
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 *
 * @author john
 */
 public class Lab3 {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
     String c;
     Lab3 classy  = new Lab3();
     Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.print("Which character would you like to display?");

          c = input.next();

        System.out.println("My name is Jonathan");
        classy.displayLetterJ(c);
        classy.displayLetterO(c);
        classy.displayLetterN(c);
        classy.displayLetterA(c);
        classy.displayLetterT(c);
        classy.displayLetterH(c);
        classy.displayLetterA(c);
        classy.displayLetterN(c);

      }//end of main
public void displayLetterJ(String c) {
    System.out.println("  "+c+c+c);
    System.out.println("    " +c);
    System.out.println("    " +c);
    System.out.println(c + "   " + c);
    System.out.println(c+ c+ c + c +c);

 }
 public void displayLetterA(String c){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("   "+c);
    System.out.println("  "+c+" "+c);
    System.out.println(" "+c+" "+c+" "+c);
    System.out.println(c+"     "+c);
    System.out.println(c+"     "+c);

}
  public void displayLetterO(String c){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("  "+c+c);
    System.out.println(" "+c+"  "+c);
    System.out.println(c+"    "+c);
    System.out.println(c+"   "+c);
    System.out.println("  "+c+c);

}
  public void displayLetterN(String c){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(c+"    "+c);
    System.out.println(c+" "+c+"  "+c);
    System.out.println(c+"  "+c+" "+c);
    System.out.println(c+"   "+c+c);
    System.out.println(c+"    "+c);

}
 public void displayLetterH(String c){//H accessor
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(c+"   "+c);
    System.out.println(c+"   "+c);
    System.out.println(c+c+c+c+c);
    System.out.println(c+"   "+c);
    System.out.println(c+"   "+c);

}
  public void displayLetterT(String c){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(c+c+c+c+c);
    System.out.println("  "+c);
    System.out.println("  "+c);
    System.out.println("  "+c);
    System.out.println("  "+c);

    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks, so all I had to do was define the c string in the main method and then pass it as an argument to the other methods. This works. I think the other answers below would also work but at my current level this is the easiest to understand for now.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is that if a variable is not `static` then it's attached to an instance of a class, thus you can't refer it from a `static` context. This because a non static variable represents a sort of state of a specific instance.

Your `main()` is static, so `c = ..` is illegal. Try with `classy.c = ..` so that you will be referring to the specific `String` of the instance of `Lab3` you create in your static method.

Answer (score 0):

There are several aproaches to face the issue, one could be:
Define the c String inside main mehod and then pass c String as an argument to all your methods.

Other approach could be define c String as a class atribute (non static), an then inside your methods use "this.c" to refer to c String.

1- If you declare an attribute as static that means that the attribute will be comunitary to all instances of the class.
Non static attributes are part only of the current class instance.

Comment: Actually the second step is not necessary, they're not static methods.

Comment: Additionally the second step would probably be harmful at this point (judging from the question) since rather than actually learning how to use instance variables it would invite descending into procedural code.

Comment: Yeah that's true! I was too focus on solve the problem that I forgot that this is more a learner question than a buggy one.

Comment: The first did it quite nicely and simple.

Answer (score 0):

initialize the String only inside the method main

String c = input.next();

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your methods to use the character c in this way

```
public void displayLetterJ(String c)
{
   System.out.println("  "+c+c+c);
   System.out.println("    " +c);
   System.out.println("    " +c);
   System.out.println(c + "   " + c);
   System.out.println(c+ c+ c + c +c);
}
```

and invoke from main as

```
classy.displayLetterJ("*");
```

Comment: And how will that help him learn the difference between working with static code and instances?

Comment: it will not Matt, you're right about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud use a private instance field `c` like and public getters and setters this:

```
public class Lab3 {

   private String c;

   public void setC(String c) 
   {
        this.c = c;
   }

   public String getC() 
   {
        return this.c;
   }

....


}
```

Then you can say in your main method:

```
Lab3 classy  = new Lab3();
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Which character would you like to display?");

classy.setC(input.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public class Lab3 {
   static String c;
```

to

```
public class Lab3 {
     private String c;   
     public void setC(String c){this.c=c;}
```

Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     Lab3 classy  = new Lab3();
     Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
     c = input.next();
     classy.setC(c);

     .....
    }
```